# Comment timer bug?

Tags: support, comments

I know, Stack only allows a comment after 15 second if you are already commented

This morning I'm just trying to comment on some question.

This is the one

[who is owner in association with jpa and hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053792/who-is-owner-in-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate)

Unfortunately when I'm trying to comment on something for second time, I can't do that **even after I waited for 15 sec**.

Here is the screenshot for the same

[image]

That is fine. It is not that much frustrating. It allowed me after I refresh my page.

Am I done something weird ?? Or a bug ?

Comment: You *did* wait for 15 seconds before that second comment...?!

Comment: @deceze yes. Look at the time of my first comment. `52 seconds ago`

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: The **timer resets**. If you submitted a comment, then waited 14 seconds before submitting another, the timer would be reset, meaning you'd have to wait **another** 15 seconds before you were allowed to comment. This is likely what you've done.

Comment: @Matt Later I wait for 1 min :) No luck. Then refreshed the page.

Comment: The comments on that question look like an unnecessary argument. The bug was a positive intervention.

Comment: Did you comment on another question/answer in another tab?

Comment: @Joe No joe, nothing like that.